# How to reduce "RAM Cache + Buffer" size due to scrapy

Tags: linux, memory, cache, scraping, devops

I am running a couple of spiders in parallel by scrapyd 1.2. Each process will raise the Buffer during the crawl significantly as seen in the chart. What is this value and how can I reduce the footprint?

[image: RAM]

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the footprint? The memory would go to waste otherwise and making memory free takes computational effort.

Answer (score 2):

Linux will use available memory for various caches, mostly file related. `slabtop` command to see details.

```
how can I reduce the footprint?
```

You don't. These will be evicted quickly and automatically if needed.

Further, it is not yet a concern. 1 GB and change free on a 4 GB system is a significantly sized chunk of unused RAM.

https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Well, I updated the V-Box to 4GB from 2GB. Looking at the footprint I am asking myself if this was really needed. My question is, will it reduce the performance of the machine if I go back to 2GB since the blue bar is unclear to me.

Comment: 2 GB total, with a load similar to the 4 GB graph, would start reclaiming from cache as free decreases. Only testing can tell if the performance is adequate for your requirements. I predict it will be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. Good and helpful answer.